# How to execute gsettings within a snap package confinement

Tags: unity, gnome, java, desktop-background, snap

I'm building a snap package for my application which is java-based and downloads wallpapers from the Internet. So far so good, but now I'm adding a new feature to set the wallpaper selected and it doesn't work. This feature is implemented for Unity and Gnome 3 desktops, which provide an easy way of setting desktop wallpaper via gsettings command line tool.

This way, executing **gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri file://blablabla.jpg** you can change the desktop wallpaper directly, and my java-based application is using this tool and this command to achieve this goal.

First, when I tested wallpaperdownloader within a snap package, it complained because it didn't find gsettings binary within the snap. Now it is fixed, because I have included **libglib2.0-bin** as a stage package. Nevertheless, it doesn't work. I guess gsettings inside snap package cannot manipulate files outside the snap, and I need to directly modify those files within user's home directory. Can I achive this or it is restricted?

These are the files snapcraft.yaml and the script executed when wallpaperdownloaded is launched

snapcraft.yml

```
name: wallpaperdownloader
version: "2.2"
summary: Download and manage your favorite wallpapers from the Internet
description: WallpaperDownloader is a simple GUI Java based application for downloading and managing wallpapers from the Internet
confinement: strict

apps:
  wallpaperdownloader:
    command: wallpaperdownloader.sh
    plugs: [x11, network-bind, home]

parts:
  # Pulls the code from the original source (master branch)
  wallpaperdownloader:
    plugin: maven
    source: .
    stage-packages:
      - libglib2.0-bin

  # It will copy wallpaperdownloader script into /bin/
  # This script contains all the commands needed (sets env variables, launches the jar file...) to
  # execute the application
  exec:
    plugin: copy
    files:
      wallpaperdownloader.sh: bin/wallpaperdownloader.sh
```

wallpaperdownloader.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
# Only for packaging!
# Script for snap packaging wallpaperdownloader application. It is not related to the code itself
# Not good, needed for fontconfig
export XDG_DATA_HOME=$SNAP/usr/share
# Font Config
export FONTCONFIG_PATH=$SNAP/etc/fonts/config.d
export FONTCONFIG_FILE=$SNAP/etc/fonts/fonts.conf
export HOME=$SNAP_USER_DATA
java -jar -Duser.home=$SNAP_USER_DATA $SNAP/jar/wallpaperdownloader.jar
```

P.S.: I've tried gsettings and unity7 plugins but they didn't work althoug I only included them in snapcraft.yaml file and I didn't apply any tweak/configuration.

Thank you very much,

Eloy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I solved this problem. The trick is to use **gsettings** interface and snapcraft-desktop-helpers part fromt the Wiki (**desktop/gtk3**). These are the main files. I published them just in case they are helpful for others to solve a similar problem.

**snapcraft.yaml**

```
name: wallpaperdownloader
version: "2.2"
summary: Download and manage your favorite wallpapers from the Internet
description: WallpaperDownloader is a simple GUI Java based application for downloading and managing wallpapers from the Internet
grade: stable
confinement: strict

apps:
  wallpaperdownloader:
    command: wallpaperdownloader.sh
    plugs: [x11, network-bind, home, gsettings]

parts:
  # Pulls the code from the original source (master branch)
  # desktop/gtk3 is a snapcraft part (snapcraft-desktop-helpers) from the Wiki: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/snapcraft/parts
  # It enables desktop integration and gsettings manipulation from the confined application
  # It is necessary to use gsettings interface (see above) in order to have a fully functional
  # desktop/gtk3 part
  # Github repository for snapcraft-desktop-helpers: https://github.com/ubuntu/snapcraft-desktop-helpers
  wallpaperdownloader:
    plugin: maven
    source: ..
    after: [desktop/gtk3]

  # It will copy wallpaperdownloader script into /bin/
  # This script contains all the commands needed (sets env variables, launches the jar file...) to
  # execute the application
  exec:
    plugin: dump
    source: scripts
```

**wallpaperdownloader.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
# Only for packaging!
# Script for snap packaging wallpaperdownloader application. It is not related to the code itself
# Not good, needed for fontconfig
export XDG_DATA_HOME=$SNAP/usr/share
# Font Config
export FONTCONFIG_PATH=$SNAP/etc/fonts/config.d
export FONTCONFIG_FILE=$SNAP/etc/fonts/fonts.conf
export HOME=$SNAP_USER_DATA
desktop-launch java -jar -Duser.home=$SNAP_USER_DATA $SNAP/jar/wallpaperdownloader.jar
```